# How do I enter the text in the specific textbox using button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a WinForms application.  There are four text boxes and one button in my form.  I am using `textBox1.SelectedText += "any string"` on a button click so it writes to the first `TextBox`.  If I add `textBox1.SelectedText += "any string."` then it writes both the textbox1 and textbox 2.

When I click textbox1 and press button then the sting only writes in the first textbox, and I click the second textbox and press the button then it write into second text box .Is there is any way to do this?

I'm using the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectedText += "abc";
    textBox2.SelectedText += "abc";          
}
```

When I focus on the control, and when we press the button focus goes to the button.  So how can we the focus on the one of the text boxes of my form after pressing the button?

Comment: I think your title is wrong: _"How do I enter text..."_, but in the question you're asking _"how can we the focus on the one of the text boxes of my form after pressing the button_"...

Comment: apologies .. i write the wrong title.it will be what you have write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
    TextBox selTB = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Enter += tb_Enter;
        textBox2.Enter += tb_Enter;
        textBox3.Enter += tb_Enter;
        textBox4.Enter += tb_Enter;
    }

    ~Form1()
    {
        textBox1.Enter -= tb_Enter;
        textBox2.Enter -= tb_Enter;
        textBox3.Enter -= tb_Enter;
        textBox4.Enter -= tb_Enter;
    }

    private void tb_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selTB = (TextBox)sender;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what you need
        selTB.SelectedText += "abc";

        // Focus last selected textbox
        if (selTB != null) selTB.Focus();
    }
```

The idea is that when you enter a textbox, you store it in `selTB`.
So whan you click button, you know which one textbox was the last selected one.

Comment: hi my problem is that when we click the textbox1 and press the button the associated text with button  goes to textbox1 only. and if i select the textbox2 and pres the button then it goes to textbox2 only not both the textboxes. how can i do that?

Comment: @vipinkatiyar: I edited my answer putting text into textbox. Is this what you need? Did you try my code? Let me know

Comment: I implemented the code Marco, but my "selTB" is always null. I dont know whats happening

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt: put a breakpoint in `tb_Enter` and check if it's called; are you sure you have textboxes?

Comment: I tried that. tb_Enter is called. But when it comes to button click event "selTb" is null.

Answer (score 2):

You can take sample as below, hope this will give you muse.

```
 public partial class Form7 : Form
 {
    private TextBox textBox = null;
    public Form7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Binding to custom event process function GetF.
        this.textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(GetF);
        this.textBox2.GotFocus += new EventHandler(GetF);
    }

    private void GetF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Keeps you selecting textbox object reference.
        textBox = sender as TextBox;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Changes you text box text.
        if (textbox != null) textBox.SelectedText += "You text";
    }
}
```

Comment: @JKhuang, vipin: I modified the code so that you do not get a NullReferenceException if no TextBox has been selected before the user clicks on the button.